# Адаптивная верстка работает не для всех устройств

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, frontend

Сейчас работаю над проектом, нужно сделать адаптивную и отзывчивую верстку сайта (ничего сверхестественного), делал такое сотни раз, но сейчас, после загрузки на хостинг, у некоторых людей с телефонов прогружаются стили для ПК(телефоны одинаковой модели, с одинаковым размером экрана), а у некоторых все работает должным образом. Сам тестил с двух телефонов с одинаковых браузеров, один работает без багов, на другом отоюражается дизайн на ПК.
В чем может ьыть проблема и как ее устранить?
Заранее спасибо

Comment: Предлагаете погадать на кофейной гуще?

Comment: Как вы видите оказание помощи в таком вопросе? Вы когда идёте что-то ремонтировать вы берёте эту вещь с собой или хотя бы какие-то фото, видео? Или когда нужно что-то починить в машине, вы просто ходите по мастерским и рассказываете о своей проблеме? Может стоит добавить больше конкретики? Хотя бы ссылку на сайт

Comment: Вот этот сайт Dobrocenter.fi

Comment: Возможно у тех ребят чьи телефоны вы взяли для тесата в браузере стоит галочка отображать как ПК браузер... или сам браузер специфический. Сколько людей, стволько видов телефонов. Воспользуйстесь для начала нормальными сервисами для тестирования под мобильные браузера.